# PowerShell - Regex put match result into a variable

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm new to Regex so don't judge hard, this is my email body:

```
INTERFACE ATM0/0/0 NOW MATCHES UD

Notification Type: INT-PHYSICAL

Host: Bla Bla 
Address: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
State: UP
Date/Time: Thu Dec 11 21:07:05 GMT 2014

...
```

I'm using VBA macros to export emails into CSV file and then I import data to PowerShell and trying to match body to RedEx code below. I need to match only this line - `INTERFACE ATM0/0/0 NOW MATCHES UD` and put result into a variable - **AlertName**, but the problem is that this line is not the same for every email. The parts of this line which always the same are `INTERFACE[space]` and `[space]NOW[space]MATCHES[space]`.

This is what I've got so far:

```
If($_ -match "(?<AlertName>[INTERFACE\s\w -/\sNOW\sMATCHES\s\w \r?\n]]+?)")
```

or

```
If($_ -match "(?<AlertName>[INTERFACE\s.*\r?\n]+?)")
```

But it doesn't work!

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you getting the email body from? Is it a string? Is it in a file? Are you somehow directly saving it to a variable?

Comment: I'm using VBA macros to export emails into CSV file and then I import data to PowerShell and trying to match needed body to above RedEx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that clear what you're doing, but something along the lines of the following will help

```powershell
if($_ -match "(INTERFACE.*NOW\s+MATCHES.*)") {
  $alertName = $matches[1]
}
```

The special variable `$matches` will contain information about the match, and `$matches[1]` will contain the first group capture - i.e. what is matched between the brackets `(...)`

Comment: Any (matched) named capturing group ( `(?<AlertName>...)` in the asker's example) will be accessible by its name as (kind of) a property of `$matches`, i.e. e.g. `$matches.AlertName`.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell stores matches from the `-match` operator in the `$matches[]` hash table.

You can also use the `[Regex]` class from .NET directly (aka, [`[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.100).aspx)) if you need more features.